# Contained database SQL 2012 - and ODBC connection creation failing

Tags: odbc, sql-server-2012, self-contained

Hi Guys Im having trouble understanding how to get around this error

When trying to create a ODCB connection we cant get past the error Error 18470 Login failed for user ####. Reason : The account is disabled.

Of course we have tested that the login to the contained database works through SMSS.

But cant google find anything on how to do a ODBC connection string to work around the .

ODBC is needed for the application that is going to be setup to use the contained databases...

Any suggestions appreciated...

Comment: I fixed this because i remembered that often when you create the ODBC connection when setting up a sql account - you can fool the gui - put the details in of the account your trying to use - password - and then simply untick the use this account box

Comment: Even though this greys out the box the details are still stored and allow you proceed to the next stages of setup so you can achieve connection by explicitly specifying the database in the next step - cut and paste - then you can go ahead and finally test the connection- this is what i did and this allowed me to create the connection.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this because i remembered that often when you create the ODBC connection when setting up a sql account - you can fool the gui - put the details in of the account your trying to use - password - and then simply untick the use this account box – MoOriginal 1 min ago edit 
Even though this greys out the box the details are still stored and allow you proceed to the next stages of setup so you can achieve connection by explicitly specifying the database in the next step - cut and paste - then you can go ahead and finally test the connection- this is what i did and this allowed me to create the connection. – MoOriginal just now edit